# Problems with sending CC and BCC copies using the Resend API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, node.js, express, resend.com

The problem I'm facing is that I pass the email addresses, the body, the subject, CC, and BCC as parameters, but I'm experiencing issues. I mean, I input valid email addresses and everything, but the emails only reach the primary recipient, and not the copies. I don't understand why, and I'm not sure if it's something related to RESEND or if I'm doing something wrong. It's strange because the emails do get sent, but when I check the RESEND logs, they don't appear to have been sent to the CC and BCC fields, even though I've included them, and the POST methods show that all this data was input. It's possible that I'm using the free version of RESEND, which may limit my ability to do this, or I might need to set up a domain. I hope you can provide some insights."
`this is my code:`
import {Resend} from 'resend'

```
export default class ResendController {

     static async sendmail (req, res ){

        try {
            const { TO,subject, body, CC, CCO } = req.body; 

            const resend = new Resend(process.env.API_KEY);
      
            const emailData = ({
              from: 'onboarding@resend.dev', 
              to: TO, 
              subject: subject,
              html: body,
              cc: CC,
              bcc: CCO
            });
            
            const emailResponse = await resend.emails.send(emailData);

            if (emailResponse && emailResponse.name === 'validation_error') {
              return res.status(422).json({ message: 'Error en la validación de correo', error: emailResponse.message });
            }
            res.status(200).json({ message: 'Correo enviado con éxito', emailData});
            
          } catch (error) {
            res.status(500).json({ message: 'Error al enviar el correo', error: error.message });
          }
        }
 }
```

```
POSTMAN:{
  "TO":"martin@alumnos.cl",
  "subject": "xd",
  "body": "hola",
  "CC":"test2@gmail.com",
   "CCO": "test@gmail.com"
}
```

I hope to receive a helpful response or a solution to my problem, or more information since there is very little information available regarding RESEND.

Comment: you have to parse the data which are you receiving  .. e.g  let data = JSON.parse( req.body )

Comment: I doubt it's that because I also enter the data for the CC and BCC fields in the code. I fill them in the code, but still, they don't get sent to the copies, and I'm not sure if it's due to limitations that RESEND might have. :c

Comment: That's the another problem

Comment: Perhaps it's due to domain changes, but regardless, I fill in those fields, and the logs display as if it was sent, but the copies are not reaching the email addresses.

Comment: are you using any module to send data?